# Could running ANALYZE on all databases on large InnoDB tables show some performance increase?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, database-tuning

So we have an old database that was fragmented until we ran `OPTIMIZE` on all tables.

The database/tables are about 100GB in size.  Tables are InnoDB with heavy read/write activity.

There are so many different queries we decided to disable query_cache due to over 1 million+ queries being pruned daily, even with 512MB cache size (with 4mb min).

Would `ANALYZE` actually improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few situations where running `ANALYZE TABLE` is beneficial

1. When you have `innodb_stats_auto_update=0` set
2. When your statistics are already "messed up" and need a fixin'

If your table statistics frequently get into a "messed up" state (which would cause bad or strange query plans), as can be the case when a table has nightly purge or bulk insert jobs, you should consider setting `innodb_stats_auto_update=0` and running a periodic manual `ANALYZE TABLE`.  Otherwise, let sleeping dogs lay and don't run it.

One caveat about `ANALYZE TABLE` is that it can cause problems if you have long running queries against the table because it flushes the table.  This means that, if you run `ANALYZE TABLE` while a query is running, no other tables will be able to access the table until the first query finishes.  I wrote [ab-analyze-innodb](https://github.com/9minutesnooze/abtools/blob/master/ab-analyze-innodb.rb) to help address this problem by searching the process list to identify whether or not the table is actively being accessed.

Comment: It seems on MySQL 5.6 the option is called `innodb_stats_auto_recalc`.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line:  Don't bother running ANALYZE on InnoDB tables.

Sure, *sometimes* ANALYZE will improve the "statistics".  But *sometimes* it will make things worse.  Hence, a "regular" ANALYZE is probably a waste.

Rolando talks about the "random dives", which is the root of the statistics going bad.  ANALYZE simply does the dives.

Percona's Xtradb and Oracles 5.6 have some extra tunables -- none of them really 'solve' the problem of statistics being sometimes bad.

All that said -- When a performance problem is identified, it is only 1 time in 1000 that ANALYZE is the main 'fix'.

MyISAM is a different matter.  A table with a *lot* of churn should probably be OPTIMIZEd monthly.  That's more for cleaning up the fragmentation, and secondarily for doing the ANALYZE.  (This applies to maybe 1 table in 10,000.)